# React - Update array in reducer Fill with objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to update the state of an item in the store.

This is working but it  is not returning the state in the format I am looking for.

The state looks like this:

```
state : {
   watchList: [
      {
        movie: {
          'name' : 'Batman'
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

however, I have been attempting to make my state look like this (i.e. not have another object inside the first object, but just an array of objects).

```
state : {

   watchList: [{'name' : 'Batman'}. {'name': 'Superman'}]

}
```

My **reducer** looks like this:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {

    switch(action.type) {

    case 'MOVIE_ADDED_TO_LIST':
        return [
            ...state,
            {
                movie: movie.event
            }
        ];

    default:
        return state;
    }

};
```

and my **action** looks like this:

```
export const addMovieToList = (movie) => {

    return {
        type: 'MOVIE_ADDED_TO_LIST',
        movie
    };

};
```

And here is how I am mapping stateToProps.

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {

    return {

        WatchListEvents: state.watchList

    }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WatchList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default (state = [], action) => {

    switch(action.type) {

    case 'MOVIE_ADDED_TO_LIST':
        return [
            ...state,
            movie.event
        ];

    default:
        return state;
    }

};
```